# How to show additional span in the middle of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need some help again from you.

I want to extend text on scrolling down, for example, when you scroll 100px down the "I trains" text goes into "I like trains".

I have it all in h1 and the "like" text is put in span.

```
<h1>I <span>like</span> trains</h1>
```

I tried giving span display:none and then animating it with jQuery's fadeIn but it's not the effect I want to achieve. It just disappears as an element, and when it shows, text on sides just jumps to left and right, but I want to animate it.

I tried also with "opacity", but there is a space between text on the sides, check fiddle. What I want to achieve is make h1 slide to sides and then show span, and to hide span and then slide the rest into center.

http://jsfiddle.net/HWESg/

Thanks for help in advance, cheers!

Comment: Using max-width instead: http://jsfiddle.net/HWESg/1/

Comment: Thanks, that made the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possibility, if you want `trains` to slide right and `like` to fade in.

HTML

```
<h1>I<span class="display"> like</span> trains</h1>
```

Javascript

```
var display = $('.display');

display.css({
    visibility: "hidden",
    fontSize: "0"
}).animate({
    fontSize: display.parent().css("fontSize")
}, 500, "linear", function () {
    $(this).css({
        opacity: "0",
        visibility: "visible"
    }).animate({
        opacity: "1"
    }, 500, "linear");
});
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/93jzA/)